# iOS UI get stuck for a few seconds after UIWebview loading starts

Tags: ios, swift

The iOS UI animation gets stuck for a few seconds while loading webview(url request).
The UIWebview is a background view, and the UIAnimation is for a Popup view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.nyforseniors.com") {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:     Notification.Name("SHOW_QUIZ"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: {     notification in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sid_quiz", sender: self)
    })
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if Manager.sharedInstance.isFirstLoad{
        Manager.sharedInstance.isFirstLoad = false
        self.openQuiz()
    }
} 

func openQuiz() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sid_welcome", sender: self)
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: If the UI is getting stuck, you likely have some code running on the main thread that should be moved to a background thread if possible. You should post your code, though, or it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I posted code here. Could you have a look at it, please?

Comment: Your notification code and the webview code are interacting with the UI and should therefore be done on the main thread

Comment: I tried with main thread originally. but it did make the app get stuck for a while, so i tried to do it in background thread. it's just a test.

Comment: in ` NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: ..., object: nil, queue: nil, using: {     notification in ...   })` you should specify the main queue. Otherwise, its not clear where the work is performed. In my experience a lot of the several second delays are because I fired a notification on a background queue, or set some ui property on a background thread.